# Position vs time of electromagnetic force

Tags: electromagnetism, calculus

I don't know if this type of question has been answered and I don't know how to search for it so I am asking it here.
Say we have two positive particles in space, with no other forces acting on each other except for the electromagnetic force. I am trying to find the position of the particles based on time.

The force between these two would be: $$F = \frac{kqq }{r^2}$$
For simplicity, let's hold one of these particles in space, and assume $mkqq = 1$.

Therefore, for the particle not held in place: $$a = \frac{1}{r^2}$$ 
The problem here is that I cannot substitute my $x = \frac{1}{2}at^2$ formula that I learned in algebra based physics. Since the acceleration isn't constant. If I were to use jerk ($x = \frac{1}{6}jt^3$), it still wouldn't work since I assume it isn't constant either.

I tried to integrate, but I don't have enough calculus knowledge to integrate r here based on dt.
I get: $$\iint a(t)dtdt = \iint \frac{1}{r^2}dtdt $$ 
$$ x(t) = \iint \frac{1}{r^2}dtdt$$
$r$ is equal to $x$ or $x + x_0$

I don't know how to get time into this equation, or how to evaluate the $\iint \frac{1}{r^2}dtdt$ being respect to dt.

Comment: *assume $mkqq=1$* Actually, it would be $kqq/m=1$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: if $a =\ddot r = \frac {1}{r^2}$ then $\dot r \ddot r = \frac {\dot r }{r^2}$, therefore $ \frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dt} (\dot r)^2 = \frac {\dot r }{r^2}$. Can you continue from here?

Comment: Hint 2: $\frac{\dot{r}}{r^2}=-\frac{d}{dt}\frac{1}{r}$.